# Insert and update on duplicate values in C# for access database

Tags: c#

I have seen other version of this problem in stack over flow and when I use it, I get error stating:

> "Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement."

I am learning just now C# and I don't know what I am missing, I am using the following commandtext. Suggest me where I am wrong.

```
"Insert into weightsofsalts(ID,WeightOfSalts) values(@id,@weightofsalts) on duplicate key update WeightOfSalts =@weightofsalts";
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a semicolon at the end of the SQL statement?

Comment: Yes, I tried by putting semicolon at the end of the sql statement, I still get the same error

Comment: Yes, I am using access for this query

Answer (score 0):

MS Access won't support `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

You have to insert statement first and then check to see if error 3022 occurred, which indicates the row already exists. So you have to update.

Comment: @KamalSubodh MS Access won't support ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE